# How to setup Apache virtual host based on name?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a server with IP address `192.168.1.65`

I want to setup virtual hosting such that:

- if I access through http://192.168.1.65/, it will lead me to DocumentRoot A
- else if I access through http://xyz.com/, it will lead me to DocumentRoot B

(xyz.com is already pointing to 192.168.1.65 in dns server)

Answer (score 3):

The "default host" should be your doc-root A. Then add name based virtual hosts for B and any additional domains.

In your main config file default configurations including DocumentRoot should be setup for hosting site A. Also you should have a line such as `NameVirtualHost *:80` to setup virtual hosting for everything on port 80. Then in your virtual host file you will have something like this for each domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xyz.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/B
</VirtualHost>
```

Anything without a virtual host and matching server name will use the default host, with your docroot set to A.

Comment: i have added a name based virtual host. the problem now seem that since the IP and the domain are pointing to the same machine using same port, when i type the domain, the browser lead me to DocRoot A which is the same as the ip address

Comment: Yang it is possible to host different sites for the IP address when called directly and various domains that point to the same IP address. Your problem is your configs ... if you have the default setup correctly to catch unknown names, this will catch the IP address-as-name senario as well. It sounds like your virtualhost is not being recognized at all.

Comment: what are the setting  i need to mod? i mean the 'default setup' catching unknown names.

Comment: i do have the NameVirtualHost *.80 specified in ports.conf file. and the virtual host file is very similar to yours (only diff are mine have ServerAlias option specified). I use the -S option to check the syntax of the vhost file, it says OK.

Comment: The most relevant settings are in my answer already, including haveing a DocumentRoot directive in the common config file outside of any VirtualHost container. If you are still having trouble it might be helpful to post your current configs to http://pastebin.com or some such place so we can look at them.

Comment: Hi Caleb, this is the default vhost file: http://pastebin.com/30zPbUsz and this is the one i created for name based vhost: http://pastebin.com/kzQVJL65

Comment: @Yang your "default vhost" is not at all what I was refering to. Everything there is inside a VirtualHost container. You need to get those to just be the default values for the server. Strip the VirtualHost wrapper tags from that and go through the main server config, setting the values from there as the server defaults. Then your name based virtual host should kick in and pick up the named requests.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to setup a "default host" not a "default virtual host". The virtual host will be the name based ones that are sets of modified values from the server defaults. The IP address calls should reach just the server defaults, not any particular VirtualHost container.

Comment: do you mean i remove that vhost and add the options to apache2.conf files?

Comment: @Yang: Yes I do.